# Sending elementcollection inside singletonlist

Tags: java, jpa, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I need to send **comment** element to HTML.

There is no `comment DTO`, it is `TaskComment` actually. I defined like that inside Task class

```
    @ElementCollection
private Set<TaskComment> comments;
```

Insıde `taskcomment`, because it is `model` class, there are some attributes like:

```
 private String message;

public String getUser() {
        return user;
    }

private ZonedDateTime createdAt = ZonedDateTime.now();

private String createdAtString;
```

I define `params` like that

```
 Map<String, Object> params = prepareParams(task);
```

I put comment inside this like this:

```
params.put("commentsAdded", Collections.singletonList(comment));
```

and without any problem, i can see my html like this:

```
<tbody>
    <tr th:each="addedComment : ${commentsAdded}">
        <td th:text="${addedComment.user}">user...</td>
        <td th:text="${addedComment.message}">message ...</td>
    </tr>    </tbody>
```

I dont know why we use for each, there is only one comment object.

but when i want to put elementcollection of `comment`, it gives error.

```
@ElementCollection
private Set<TaskComment> comments;
```

i tried this

```
params.put("commentsInTask",new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(task.getComments())));
```

but in html

```
<tr th:each="addedComment : ${commentsInTask}">
    <td th:text="${addedComment.user}">user...</td>
    <td th:text="${addedComment.message}">message ...</td>
```

for

```
<td th:text="${addedComment.user}">user...</td>
```

that line it gave error. I think it stopped after error, probably would give error for other lin too.

I tried to put `singletonMap` but it is not hashmap. It is collection.

I tried to put

```
 params.put("commentsInTaskk",new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(task.getComments())));
```

but i couldnot make it work. I thought it would work. Or i did wrong.

What do you suggest?

I use spring boot + intellij.

For example when i use this in html

```
<tr th:each="addedComment : ${commentsInTask}">
        <td th:text="${addedComment.key}">key ...</td>
        <td th:text="${addedComment.value.user}">value.user...</td>
```

the error is:

> org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception
>   evaluating SpringEL expression: "addedComment.key"
>   (task_comment_cta:29)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did like this and worked

```
<tr th:each="allComments : ${commentsInTask}">
<tr th:each="comment : ${allComments}">
    <td th:text="${comment.user}">user ...</td>
```